# R - Print table with columns sums below

Tags: r

Example: I have a simple data frame

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02")
                 , sales_a = c(2,3)
                 , sales_b = c(1,1)
                 , diff=c(1,2))
```

I am currently printing this df using kable in an RMarkDown document. I would like to produce a row underneath with the sums of the columns (not date) with a line separating the df from the totals. Is this possible with any R package without writing latex code which I'm not too familiar with?

Thanks

Comment: This is a question about markdown (specifically [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) and is unique to neither R nor `knitr`. To my knowledge, though, tables in markdown are specifically simple and straight-forward; I do now know of a way to do what you want. (That is, you can draw a line between a header row and the first row, or perhaps between all rows (?), but I have not seen the ability in markdown to have a distinct "footer row" stylistically.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you can draw a line between the last and second-to-last rows in markdown. But calculating and including a summary row is relatively straight-forward.

(BTW: I've included `stringsAsFactors` in the data.frame, for preference and ease of handling new strings.)

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02")
               , sales_a = c(2,3)
               , sales_b = c(1,1)
               , diff=c(1,2)
               , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
func <- function(z) if (is.numeric(z)) sum(z) else ''
sumrow <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, func))
sumrow
#   date sales_a sales_b diff
# 1            5       2    3
```

It's relatively straight-forward to combine with the whole data.frame:

```
library(knitr)
kable(rbind(df, sumrow))
# |date       | sales_a| sales_b| diff|
# |:----------|-------:|-------:|----:|
# |2016-01-01 |       2|       1|    1|
# |2016-01-02 |       3|       1|    2|
# |           |       5|       2|    3|
```

If you want the ability to highlight/label the specific summary row:

```
kable(rbind(cbind(' '=' ', df),
            cbind(' '='Total', sumrow)))
# |      |date       | sales_a| sales_b| diff|
# |:-----|:----------|-------:|-------:|----:|
# |      |2016-01-01 |       2|       1|    1|
# |      |2016-01-02 |       3|       1|    2|
# |Total |           |       5|       2|    3|
```

The "Total" label can of course be put anywhere. You might try to add a row (of characters) manually, but I'm not certain it would look right.

Comment: Thank you, I like the new column with the total, it looks neat. It's a shame there's no way of adding a forced line break.

Comment: @Anon.user111 The problem is that Markdown is (intentionally) severely limited in its formatting options. I therefore never understood how it became a target format for tools that generate formatted text; it’s really badly suited for the task.

Answer (score 6):

I took the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/36069586/8076560 as an inspiration to create the following in R with RStudio. The table can then be exported (knit) to pdf/html as needed.

> [image: Screenshot of Finished Table]

And now to the code...

````
```{r name-of-chunk, echo=FALSE}    

# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

# Make lists
types <- c("Heating", "Water Heating", "Electricity")
heat_per_person <- c (9.59, 1.32, 1.95)
heat_per_area <- c(95.26, 13.55, 20.03)

# Make dataframe
results_df <- data.frame(types , heat_per_person, heat_per_area, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Sum the last row of each column if numeric 
func <- function(z) if (is.numeric(z)) sum(z) else '' 
sumrow <- as.data.frame(lapply(results_df, func))

# Give name to the first element of the new data frame created above
sumrow[1] <- "Total"

# Add the original and new data frames together
summed_results_df <- rbind(results_df, sumrow)

# Name the columns
colnames <- data.frame("Service", "Amount per Person","Amount per Area", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(summed_results_df) <- colnames

# Make Table
kable(summed_results_df, caption = "Normalized Annual Energy Demand", booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")) %>%
  row_spec(dim(summed_results_df)[1], bold = T) %>% # format last row
  column_spec(1, italic = T) # format first column

```
````

You can refer to the table in the Rmarkdown/ Rmd text with the name of the code chunk as shown here: `\@ref(tab:name-of-chunk)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a tidyverse solution, using the `booktabs` kable option.

The `add_totals` function is kept simple. It displays “Total” in any non-numerical column.

The horizontal line above the totals is added by using the `linesep` kable option. This option defaults `c("", "", "", "", "\\addlinespace")`. This means that additional space is added after every fifth line, whereas after every first to fourth line, nothing (`""`) is added. Instead of this default, I am adding a `\midrule` after the second-to-last line: `c(rep("", nrow(df) - 2), "\\midrule")`. This means that nothing (`""`) is added after as many rows as the number of rows minus two (`nrow(df) - 2`), and after the next line (the second-to-last line), a horizontal line (`\midrule`) is added.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r showcase, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(date=c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02")
                 , sales_a = c(2,3)
                 , sales_b = c(1,1)
                 , diff=c(1,2))

add_totals <- function(x) x %>%
    ungroup %>% # you never know ...
    bind_rows(summarise(., across(where(is.numeric), sum),
                        across(where(is.character), ~ "Total")))

df %>%
    add_totals %>%
    kable(booktabs = TRUE,
          linesep = c(rep("", nrow(.) - 2), "\\midrule"))
```
````

This produces the following output:

[image: Booktab example with Totals line and midrule above]